# R shinydashboard Nested box not rendered when uncollapsing initially collapse main box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In a `dashboardPage` from the package `shinydashboard` in a `shiny` app, when using nested boxes, an inside box not collapsed by default is not rendered when the main box (which is initially collapsed) is uncollapsed.

**Note 1:** collapsing and uncollapsing the inside box triggers the rendering, but it clearly degrades the user experience.

Here is a MWE:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE), dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            box(
                title = "Inputs", collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = TRUE,
                width = 12,
                box(
                    title = "Test", collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = FALSE,
                    uiOutput("test1_ui"),
                    uiOutput("test2_ui")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$test1_ui <- renderUI({
        tagList("RENDER ME")
    })
    output$test2_ui <- renderUI({
        actionButton("click", label = "Click Me")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Session info:**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- R 4.1.0
- shinydashboard 0.7.1 and shiny 1.6.0

**Note 2:** the same problem was observed before updating to R 4.1.0

**Note 3:** This issue was already raised [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/234) but I am really not sure how to use the suggested workaround.

**Question:** Does anyone have a solution ? or can explain the workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/234) ?